# Windows 7 keyboard become unusable when rebooting from Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, keyboard, multi-boot

I installed Windows 7 on my laptop (at `C:\`), then I installed Ubuntu 11.10.

Every time I exit Ubuntu and reboot to Windows 7, at the welcome screen, the keyboard become unusable. If I restart my laptop and choose to boot to Windows 7, the keyboard become usable again.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you dualboot when dozens of virtualisation solutions just nibble around. Say virtualbox or vmware player or virtualpc?

Same problem may show also rebooting other way with USB netcards dead in Liinux after Windows. Systems expect BIOS to initalize devices well but sometimes they unintialize them so that BIOS cannot reset them. The only solution is to shut down and power on each time. Update BIOS, but do not put big hopes in that.

Comment: when I restarted my laptop in ubuntu, there was a usb stick pluged in...I will try some times without usb stick. thanks.

Comment: Not related. I am saying that Linux shuts down keyboard so good that BIOS and Windows cannot get it back.